# Java Pass Array of Arguments

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

How do you pass an array of arguments, like python's `f(*args)`?

#### Exampes from other languages:

Python: `f(*args)`

JavaScript: `f.apply(this, args)`

Ruby: `f(*args)`

Similar to [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java) and [varargs and the '...' argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument), but the function declaration doesn't use spread syntax.

```
void draw(int x, int y) {
    ...
}
```

In addition, is this possible when the arguments are not all the same type?

```
void draw(int x, String y) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Anything—let's say an array of two numbers, where the function takes two int parameters

Comment: Already noted in the description how this question is different.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. Perfectly accurate question. If you downvote, please explain why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java)

Comment: @GergelyBacso **Already noted in the description how this question is different.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [varargs and the '...' argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656901/varargs-and-the-argument)

Comment: Again, this is different because the method **declaration** doesn't use spread syntax.

Comment: I'm confused, I think in Java the equivalent is the reflection API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876300/java-reflection-passing-in-a-arraylist-as-argument-for-the-method-to-be-invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with reflection, but it's probably more performant to use cached method handles that you initialize once, then reuse as many times as you need.

```
class SpreadInvoker {
    public static void draw1(int x, String y) {
        System.out.printf("draw1(%s, %s)%n", x, y);
    }

    public void draw2(int x, int y) {
        System.out.printf("draw2(%s, %s)%n", x, y);
    }

    static MethodHandle DRAW1;
    static MethodHandle DRAW2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        DRAW1 = MethodHandles.lookup()
                             .findStatic(
                                 SpreadInvoker.class,
                                 "draw1",
                                 MethodType.methodType(
                                     void.class,
                                     int.class,
                                     String.class
                                 )
                             )
                             .asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);

        DRAW2 = MethodHandles.lookup()
                             .findVirtual(
                                 SpreadInvoker.class,
                                 "draw2",
                                 MethodType.methodType(
                                     void.class,
                                     int.class,
                                     int.class
                                 )
                             ).asSpreader(Object[].class, 2);

        SpreadInvoker instance = new SpreadInvoker();

        final Object[] args1 = { 13, "twenty-six" };
        final Object[] args2 = { 13, 26 };

        DRAW1.invoke(args1);           // SpreadInvoker.draw1(13, "twenty-six")
        DRAW2.invoke(instance, args2); // instance.draw2(13, 26)
    }
}
```

Output:

> draw1(13, twenty-six)
>   draw2(13, 26)

Note, however, that this is the sort of thing you'd do if you *don't know* what method you need to call at compile time.  This sort of thing should almost never be necessary.

Comment: Yup, there's always something to learn even after 10+ years of Java :)

Answer (score 1):

This style of calling methods is not usual for Java language, but possible with reflection API:

```
    Method drawMethod = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("draw", new Class[] { int.class, int.class });
    drawMethod.invoke(null, (Object[]) args);
```

[Further reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: `null` is eligible for first argument of `invoke` only if the method is declared static

Comment: Thank you! How would this be accomplished when the arguments are not all the same type?

Comment: You should pass desired argument types as second argument to `getDeclaredMethod`. Obviously, this can only work if corresponding method is actually declared.

Comment: Oh great! Because Object[] can contain anything?

Comment: Expected type of second argument of `invoke` is `Object[]`. Cast there is just for clarity.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I'm getting `error: unreported exception NoSuchMethodException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        java.lang.reflect.Method solution = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("draw", new Class[] { int.class, int.class });`
for
`class YourClass {
    public void draw(int x, int y) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar in java, but all of them must be the same type:

Java: `f(String... args);`

It calls "Varargs" so you can google by this world for more information

Comment: Thank you! Does this work when the function isn't declared using special syntax?

Comment: I said, does this work when the function isn't **declared** using special syntax? I.e. how would you call the example given in the question statement?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean under "special syntax". If you mean that you can just take arguments as variable without declaring it like in JavaScript - then no.

Comment: about calling - yes, you do not need "special" syntax. i.e you can call 
 it like f("A"); f("A", "B", "C")

Comment: Got it, so given a normal method in Java, it's impossible to pass an array of arguments like in Python?

Comment: I don't want to pass the array as a single argument. I want to apply the array as N arguments.

Comment: If this is only possible using reflection, how would it be done?

Comment: I did not mean to ask whether you can pass one argument. I asked whether you can pass an array of arguments. The elements of the array are **arguments** to the function. They are "the things you pass in".

Answer (score 0):

To pass unknown number of variables you would do:

```
public void getNumber(int...args){
      ...
}
```

to retrieve you would do:

```
args[0], args[1], args[2], ...
```